# Audio frequency trainer / tester using Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, html5, audio

I'm making an audio frequency trainer as a learning exercise. It could be useful for audio technicians who need to recognize audio frequencies (eg. when ringing out feedback during a live concert or soundcheck).

A few days ago [I posted the humble beginnings](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203209/random-tone-generator-using-web-audio-api). I got very useful feedback and went further. [Here is a working example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MaxVMH/Lbr8okj3/4/) & [here is the full code on GitHub](https://github.com/MaxVMH/frequency-trainer/tree/v.0.0.4-alpha). In case anyone prefers the devtools in their own browser, here is a [working example online](http://www.frequencytrainer.com).

Before I continue adding more functions, I would like to know what you guys think of this so far. Any feedback is welcome!

```js
let toneContext = null;
let toneGenerator = null;
let toneAmplifier = null;

function startFrequencyTrainer(difficultyMode, previousFrequency) {
    let frequencies = null;
    let frequency = null;

    // Create objects
    toneContext = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    toneAmplifier = toneContext.createGain();

    // Pick a frequency
    frequencies = getFrequencies(difficultyMode);
    frequency = getNewFrequency(frequencies, previousFrequency);

    return {
        frequencies,
        frequency
    };
}

function stopFrequencyTrainer() {
    toneContext.close();
}

function startToneGenerator(frequency, volumeControl, startTimer, stopTimer) {
    // Create and configure the oscillator
    toneGenerator = toneContext.createOscillator();
    toneGenerator.type = 'sine'; // could be sine, square, sawtooth or triangle
    toneGenerator.frequency.value = frequency;

    // Connect toneGenerator -> toneAmplifier -> output
    toneGenerator.connect(toneAmplifier);
    toneAmplifier.connect(toneContext.destination);

    // Set the gain volume
    toneAmplifier.gain.value = volumeControl.value / 100;

    // Fire up the toneGenerator
    toneGenerator.start(toneContext.currentTime + startTimer);
    toneGenerator.stop(toneContext.currentTime + startTimer + stopTimer);
}

function stopToneGenerator() {
    if (toneGenerator) {
        toneGenerator.disconnect();
    }
}

function changeVolume(volumeControl) {
    toneAmplifier.gain.value = volumeControl.value / 100;
}

function getFrequencies(difficultyMode) {
    let frequencies = null;

    if (difficultyMode === 'easy') {
        frequencies = ["250", "800", "2500", "8000"];
    } else if (difficultyMode === 'normal') {
        frequencies = ["100", "200", "400", "800", "1600", "3150", "6300", "12500"];
    } else if (difficultyMode === 'hard') {
        frequencies = ["80", "125", "160", "250", "315", "500", "630", "1000", "1250", "2000", "2500", "4000", "5000", "8000", "10000", "16000"];
    } else if (difficultyMode === 'pro') {
        frequencies = ["20", "25", "31.5", "40", "50", "63", "80", "100", "125", "160", "200", "250", "315", "400", "500", "630", "800", "1000", "1250", "1600", "2000", "2500", "3150", "4000", "5000", "6300", "8000", "10000", "12500", "16000", "20000"];
    }

    return frequencies;
}

function getNewFrequency(frequencies, previousFrequency) {
    let newFrequency = null;

    newFrequency = frequencies[Math.floor(Math.random() * frequencies.length)];
    // Avoid getting the same frequency twice in a row
    while (newFrequency === previousFrequency) {
        newFrequency = frequencies[Math.floor(Math.random() * frequencies.length)];
    }

    return newFrequency;
}

function frequencyFormatter(frequency) {
    let frequencyFormatted = null;

    if (frequency > 999) {
        frequencyFormatted = frequency / 1000 + ' k';
    } else {
        frequencyFormatted = frequency + ' ';
    }

    return frequencyFormatted;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:900" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Frequency Trainer</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <br />
            <button type="button" id="start-button" class="control-button">Start</button>
            <button type="button" id="stop-button" class="control-button">Stop</button>
            <button type="button" id="next-button" class="control-button">Next</button><br />
            <br />
            Volume:<br />
            <input type="range" id="volume-control" class="volume-control" min="0" max="20" value="2" step="0.1" /><br />
            <br />
            <button type="button" id="difficulty-easy" class="difficulty-button" data-difficulty="easy">Easy</button>
            <button type="button" id="difficulty-normal" class="difficulty-button" data-difficulty="normal">Normal</button>
            <button type="button" id="difficulty-hard" class="difficulty-button" data-difficulty="hard">Hard</button>
            <button type="button" id="difficulty-pro" class="difficulty-button" data-difficulty="pro">Pro</button><br />
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    (function () {
        let difficultyMode = 'easy'; // default difficulty mode
        let frequencyTrainer = startFrequencyTrainer(difficultyMode, null);
        let frequency = frequencyTrainer.frequency;
        let frequencyContainers = null;

        // Control buttons
        let startButton = document.getElementById('start-button');
        startButton.onclick = function () {
            stopToneGenerator();
            startToneGenerator(frequency, volumeControl, 0, 3);
        };
        let stopButton = document.getElementById('stop-button');
        stopButton.onclick = function () {
            stopToneGenerator();
        };
        let nextButton = document.getElementById('next-button');
        nextButton.onclick = function () {
            stopToneGenerator();
            stopFrequencyTrainer();
            frequency = startFrequencyTrainer(difficultyMode, frequency).frequency;
            startToneGenerator(frequency, volumeControl, 0.05, 3);
        };
        let volumeControl = document.getElementById('volume-control');
        volumeControl.oninput = function () {
            changeVolume(volumeControl);
        };

        function fillFrequencyGrid(frequencies) {
            let frequencyFormatted = null;
            let frequencyGrid = document.getElementsByClassName('grid')[0];

            frequencyGrid.innerHTML = '';
            frequencies.forEach(function (frequency) {
                frequencyFormatted = frequencyFormatter(frequency);
                frequencyGrid.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="frequency-container" data-frequency="' + frequency + '">' + frequencyFormatted + 'Hz</div>');
            });
        }

        function makeFrequencyGridInteractive() {
            frequencyContainers = document.getElementsByClassName('frequency-container');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(frequencyContainers, function (frequencyContainer) {
                frequencyContainer.onclick = function () {
                    let frequencyChosen = frequencyContainer.getAttribute('data-frequency');
                    let frequencyChosenFormatted = frequencyFormatter(frequencyChosen);

                    stopToneGenerator();
                    if (frequencyChosen === frequency) {
                        if (window.confirm(frequencyChosenFormatted + 'Hz is correct!\nLet\'s try another one!')) {
                            stopFrequencyTrainer();
                            frequency = startFrequencyTrainer(difficultyMode, frequency).frequency;
                            startToneGenerator(frequency, volumeControl, 0.05, 3);
                        }
                    } else {
                        window.alert(frequencyChosenFormatted + 'Hz is not correct.\nPlease try again.');
                        startToneGenerator(frequency, volumeControl, 0.05, 3);
                    }
                };
            });
        }

        // Generate frequency grid
        fillFrequencyGrid(frequencyTrainer.frequencies);
        makeFrequencyGridInteractive();

        // Difficulty buttons
        let difficultyButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('difficulty-button');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(difficultyButtons, function (difficultyButton) {
            difficultyButton.onclick = function () {
                stopToneGenerator();
                stopFrequencyTrainer();
                difficultyMode = difficultyButton.getAttribute('data-difficulty');
                frequencyTrainer = startFrequencyTrainer(difficultyMode, frequency);
                frequency = frequencyTrainer.frequency;
                fillFrequencyGrid(frequencyTrainer.frequencies);
                makeFrequencyGridInteractive();
            };
        });
    }());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## General Feedback

This looks like a neat little program. I admit I hadn't explored the audio APIs before reading [your first post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/203209/120114) and as a musician I enjoy seeing technology connect audio and visual elements. The colors on the frequency contains is a nice array. Good work! There are a few things mentioned below that can help optimize memory as well as the coding style. The feedback comes both from my experience as well as reading articles [like this one](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/02/stop-writing-slow-javascript/).

## Suggestions

### Event delegation

Use event delegation instead of manually setting the `onclick` handlers.

For example, instead of assigning a callback function to the `onclick` attribute of each frequency button, use [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for the `click` event, and inspect `event.target` to see if it has the class `frequency-container`:

```
frequencyGrid.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.classList.contains('frequency-container')) {
        let frequencyChosen = target.getAttribute('data-frequency');
```

Not only does it allow the click handler to be set once on a container but also it can avoid memory leaks (since the frequencies can be removed from the DOM). See answers to [DOM: why is this a memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15761094/1575353) for more information.

#### Strict Mode

Many of the functions in the javascript section have `'use strict';` at the first line, while the IIFE on the page has that directive at the start. Why not make the Javascript section more like the IIFE?

#### Use `const` as default instead of `let`

It is advisable to use `const` instead of `let` for any variable that doesn't need to be re-assigned. Then when you determine re-assignment is necessary, use `let`. That way there will be less chance of overwriting a value.

On that same topic, there is little point in assigning a value of `null` shortly before assigning an actual value - e.g. the following lines come in `startFrequencyTrainer()`:

> ```
> let frequencies = null;
> let frequency = null;
>
> // Create objects
> toneContext = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
> toneAmplifier = toneContext.createGain();
>
> // Pick a frequency
> frequencies = getFrequencies(difficultyMode);
> frequency = getNewFrequency(frequencies, previousFrequency);
> ```

Instead `frequencies` and `frequency` can be declared as a `const` when assigned.

```
// Create objects
toneContext = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
toneAmplifier = toneContext.createGain();

// Pick a frequency
const frequencies = getFrequencies(difficultyMode);
const frequency = getNewFrequency(frequencies, previousFrequency);
```

The same is true for `newFrequency` in `getNewFrequency()`:

> ```
> let newFrequency = null;
> newFrequency = frequencies[Math.floor(Math.random() * frequencies.length)];
> ```

This can be simplified to a single line, since there is no point in the value being `null` before it is assigned:

```
let newFrequency = frequencies[Math.floor(Math.random() * frequencies.length)];
```

#### Use spread operator

Use [the spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for things like putting the HTMLElement collections into an array instead of using `Array.prototype.forEach.call`.

So lines like these:

> ```
> let difficultyButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('difficulty-button');
> Array.prototype.forEach.call(difficultyButtons, function (difficultyButton) {
> ```

Can be changed to this:

```
let difficultyButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('difficulty-button');
[...difficultyButtons].forEach( function (difficultyButton) {
```

### Selecting frequencies by difficulty

There isn't anything wrong with the function `getFrequencies()` but it could be shortened by declaring a mapping outside the function:

```
const frequenciesByDifficulty = {
'easy': ["250", "800", "2500", "8000"],
  'normal': ["100", "200", "400", "800", "1600", "3150", "6300", "12500"],
  'hard': ["80", "125", "160", "250", "315", "500", "630", "1000", "1250", "2000", "2500", "4000", "5000", "8000", "10000", "16000"],
  'pro': ["20", "25", "31.5", "40", "50", "63", "80", "100", "125", "160", "200", "250", "315", "400", "500", "630", "800", "1000", "1250", "1600", "2000", "2500", "3150", "4000", "5000", "6300", "8000", "10000", "12500", "16000", "20000"]
};
```

Then that function can simply look up frequencies from that mapping:

```
function getFrequencies(difficultyMode) {
    if (difficultyMode in frequenciesByDifficulty) {
      return frequenciesByDifficulty[difficultyMode];
    }
    //fallback
    return null;
}
```

That way the frequencies can be altered without having to modify the function.

#### formatter function

This is probably just a personal preference - the function `formatterFunction()` could be simplified by removing `frequencyFormatted` and simply return the values as soon as they are ready:

```
function frequencyFormatter(frequency) {
    if (frequency > 999) {
        return frequency / 1000 + ' k';
    } 
    return frequency + ' ';    
}
```

And if you wanted, that could be simplifed using an arrow function (as could all functions):

```
const frequencyFormatter = frequency => frequency > 999 ? frequency / 1000 + ' k' : frequency + ' ';
```

#### Use a function partial for the volume change callback

Use [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a [partially applied function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions) for the `oninput` callback:

```
volumeControl.oninput = changeVolume.bind(null, volumeControl);
```

### Updated code

See snippet below. I didn't change all the functions to arrow functions but could...

```js
'use strict';
let toneContext = null;
let toneGenerator = null;
let toneAmplifier = null;

function startFrequencyTrainer(difficultyMode, previousFrequency) {
  // Create objects
  toneContext = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  toneAmplifier = toneContext.createGain();

  // Pick a frequency
  const frequencies = getFrequencies(difficultyMode);
  const frequency = getNewFrequency(frequencies, previousFrequency);

  return {
    frequencies,
    frequency
  };
}

function stopFrequencyTrainer() {
  toneContext.close();
}

function startToneGenerator(frequency, volumeControl, startTimer, stopTimer) {
  // Create and configure the oscillator
  toneGenerator = toneContext.createOscillator();
  toneGenerator.type = 'sine'; // could be sine, square, sawtooth or triangle
  toneGenerator.frequency.value = frequency;

  // Connect toneGenerator -> toneAmplifier -> output
  toneGenerator.connect(toneAmplifier);
  toneAmplifier.connect(toneContext.destination);

  // Set the gain volume
  toneAmplifier.gain.value = volumeControl.value / 100;

  // Fire up the toneGenerator
  toneGenerator.start(toneContext.currentTime + startTimer);
  toneGenerator.stop(toneContext.currentTime + startTimer + stopTimer);
}

function stopToneGenerator() {
  if (toneGenerator) {
    toneGenerator.disconnect();
  }
}

function changeVolume(volumeControl) {
  toneAmplifier.gain.value = volumeControl.value / 100;
}
const frequenciesByDifficulty = {
  'easy': ["250", "800", "2500", "8000"],
  'normal': ["100", "200", "400", "800", "1600", "3150", "6300", "12500"],
  'hard': ["80", "125", "160", "250", "315", "500", "630", "1000", "1250", "2000", "2500", "4000", "5000", "8000", "10000", "16000"],
  'pro': ["20", "25", "31.5", "40", "50", "63", "80", "100", "125", "160", "200", "250", "315", "400", "500", "630", "800", "1000", "1250", "1600", "2000", "2500", "3150", "4000", "5000", "6300", "8000", "10000", "12500", "16000", "20000"]
};

function getFrequencies(difficultyMode) {
  if (difficultyMode in frequenciesByDifficulty) {
    return frequenciesByDifficulty[difficultyMode];
  }
  //fallback
  return null;
}

function getNewFrequency(frequencies, previousFrequency) {
  let newFrequency = frequencies[Math.floor(Math.random() * frequencies.length)];
  // Avoid getting the same frequency twice in a row
  while (newFrequency === previousFrequency) {
    newFrequency = frequencies[Math.floor(Math.random() * frequencies.length)];
  }
  return newFrequency;
}

function frequencyFormatter(frequency) {
  if (frequency > 999) {
    return frequency / 1000 + ' k';
  }
  return frequency + ' ';
}

(function() {
  'use strict';
  let difficultyMode = 'easy'; // default difficulty mode
  let frequencyTrainer = startFrequencyTrainer(difficultyMode);
  let frequency = frequencyTrainer.frequency;
  let frequencyContainers = null;
  const frequencyGrid = document.getElementsByClassName('grid')[0];
  const controls = document.getElementsByClassName('controls')[0];

  // Control buttons
  const startButton = document.getElementById('start-button');
  startButton.onclick = function() {
    stopToneGenerator();
    startToneGenerator(frequency, volumeControl, 0, 3);
  };
  const stopButton = document.getElementById('stop-button');
  stopButton.onclick = function() {
    stopToneGenerator();
  };
  const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-button');
  nextButton.onclick = function() {
    stopToneGenerator();
    stopFrequencyTrainer();
    frequency = startFrequencyTrainer(difficultyMode, frequency).frequency;
    startToneGenerator(frequency, volumeControl, 0.05, 3);
  };
  let volumeControl = document.getElementById('volume-control');
  volumeControl.oninput = changeVolume.bind(null, volumeControl);

  function fillFrequencyGrid(frequencies) {
    let frequencyFormatted = null;

    frequencyGrid.innerHTML = '';
    frequencies.forEach(function(frequency) {
      frequencyFormatted = frequencyFormatter(frequency);
      frequencyGrid.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="frequency-container" data-frequency="' + frequency + '">' + frequencyFormatted + 'Hz</div>');
    });
  }
  frequencyGrid.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.classList.contains('frequency-container')) {
      let frequencyChosen = target.getAttribute('data-frequency');
      let frequencyChosenFormatted = frequencyFormatter(frequencyChosen);

      stopToneGenerator();
      if (frequencyChosen === frequency) {
        if (window.confirm(frequencyChosenFormatted + 'Hz is correct!\nLet\'s try another one!')) {
          stopFrequencyTrainer();
          frequency = startFrequencyTrainer(difficultyMode, frequency).frequency;
          startToneGenerator(frequency, volumeControl, 0.05, 3);
        }
      } else {
        window.alert(frequencyChosenFormatted + 'Hz is not correct.\nPlease try again.');
        startToneGenerator(frequency, volumeControl, 0.05, 3);
      }
    }
  })


  // Generate frequency grid
  fillFrequencyGrid(frequencyTrainer.frequencies);

  // Difficulty buttons
  controls.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('difficulty-button')) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      stopToneGenerator();
      stopFrequencyTrainer();
      difficultyMode = event.target.getAttribute('data-difficulty');
      frequencyTrainer = startFrequencyTrainer(difficultyMode, frequency);
      frequency = frequencyTrainer.frequency;
      fillFrequencyGrid(frequencyTrainer.frequencies);
    }
  }, false);
}());
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
}

a {
  color: #0000BB;
}

a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 1vw);
}

.body {
  max-width: 1500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.title {
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
}

.content {
  padding: 30px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
}

.controls {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
}

.volume-control {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 80%;
}

.footer {
  padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
}

.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(84px, 1fr));
}

.frequency-container {
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(30px + 0.2vw);
  text-shadow: 0 0 25px white;
}

.frequency-container:before {
  content: '';
  padding-top: 100%;
  float: left;
}

[data-frequency="20"] {
  background: #CC2828;
}

[data-frequency="25"] {
  background: #CC3028;
}

[data-frequency="31.5"] {
  background: #CC3928;
}

[data-frequency="40"] {
  background: #CC4128;
}

[data-frequency="50"] {
  background: #CC4928;
}

[data-frequency="63"] {
  background: #CC5128;
}

[data-frequency="80"] {
  background: #CC5928;
}

[data-frequency="100"] {
  background: #CC6128;
}

[data-frequency="125"] {
  background: #CC6A28;
}

[data-frequency="160"] {
  background: #CC7228;
}

[data-frequency="200"] {
  background: #CC7A28;
}

[data-frequency="250"] {
  background: #CC8228;
}

[data-frequency="315"] {
  background: #CC8A28;
}

[data-frequency="400"] {
  background: #CC9228;
}

[data-frequency="500"] {
  background: #CC9B28;
}

[data-frequency="630"] {
  background: #CCAB28;
}

[data-frequency="800"] {
  background: #CCBB28;
}

[data-frequency="1000"] {
  background: #CCCC28;
}

[data-frequency="1250"] {
  background: #BBCC28;
}

[data-frequency="1600"] {
  background: #ABCC28;
}

[data-frequency="2000"] {
  background: #9BCC28;
}

[data-frequency="2500"] {
  background: #8ACC28;
}

[data-frequency="3150"] {
  background: #7ACC28;
}

[data-frequency="4000"] {
  background: #6ACC28;
}

[data-frequency="5000"] {
  background: #59CC28;
}

[data-frequency="6300"] {
  background: #49CC28;
}

[data-frequency="8000"] {
  background: #39CC28;
}

[data-frequency="10000"] {
  background: #28CC28;
}

[data-frequency="12500"] {
  background: #28CC39;
}

[data-frequency="16000"] {
  background: #28CC49;
}

[data-frequency="20000"] {
  background: #28CC59;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:900" />
<div class="body">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Frequency Trainer</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="start-button" class="control-button">Start</button>
    <button type="button" id="stop-button" class="control-button">Stop</button>
    <button type="button" id="next-button" class="control-button">Next</button><br />
    <br /> Volume:
    <br />
    <input type="range" id="volume-control" class="volume-control" min="0" max="20" value="2" step="0.1" /><br />
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="difficulty-easy" class="difficulty-button" data-difficulty="easy">Easy</button>
    <button type="button" id="difficulty-normal" class="difficulty-button" data-difficulty="normal">Normal</button>
    <button type="button" id="difficulty-hard" class="difficulty-button" data-difficulty="hard">Hard</button>
    <button type="button" id="difficulty-pro" class="difficulty-button" data-difficulty="pro">Pro</button><br />
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <a href="https://github.com/MaxVMH/frequency-trainer/tree/v.0.0.4-alpha">v.0.0.4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or with Arrow functions:

```js
'use strict';
let toneContext = null;
let toneGenerator = null;
let toneAmplifier = null;

const startFrequencyTrainer = (difficultyMode, previousFrequency) => {
  // Create objects
  toneContext = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  toneAmplifier = toneContext.createGain();

  // Pick a frequency
  const frequencies = getFrequencies(difficultyMode);
  const frequency = getNewFrequency(frequencies, previousFrequency);

  return {
    frequencies,
    frequency
  };
}

const stopFrequencyTrainer = _ => toneContext.close();

const startToneGenerator = (frequency, volumeControl, startTimer, stopTimer) => {
  // Create and configure the oscillator
  toneGenerator = toneContext.createOscillator();
  toneGenerator.type = 'sine'; // could be sine, square, sawtooth or triangle
  toneGenerator.frequency.value = frequency;

  // Connect toneGenerator -> toneAmplifier -> output
  toneGenerator.connect(toneAmplifier);
  toneAmplifier.connect(toneContext.destination);

  // Set the gain volume
  toneAmplifier.gain.value = volumeControl.value / 100;

  // Fire up the toneGenerator
  toneGenerator.start(toneContext.currentTime + startTimer);
  toneGenerator.stop(toneContext.currentTime + startTimer + stopTimer);
}

const stopToneGenerator = _ => {
  if (toneGenerator) {
    toneGenerator.disconnect();
  }
}

const changeVolume = volumeControl => toneAmplifier.gain.value = volumeControl.value / 100;

const frequenciesByDifficulty = {
  'easy': ["250", "800", "2500", "8000"],
  'normal': ["100", "200", "400", "800", "1600", "3150", "6300", "12500"],
  'hard': ["80", "125", "160", "250", "315", "500", "630", "1000", "1250", "2000", "2500", "4000", "5000", "8000", "10000", "16000"],
  'pro': ["20", "25", "31.5", "40", "50", "63", "80", "100", "125", "160", "200", "250", "315", "400", "500", "630", "800", "1000", "1250", "1600", "2000", "2500", "3150", "4000", "5000", "6300", "8000", "10000", "12500", "16000", "20000"]
};
const getFrequencies = difficultyMode => {
  if (difficultyMode in frequenciesByDifficulty) {
    return frequenciesByDifficulty[difficultyMode];
  }
  //fallback
  return null;
}

const getNewFrequency = (frequencies, previousFrequency) => {
  let newFrequency = frequencies[Math.floor(Math.random() * frequencies.length)];
  // Avoid getting the same frequency twice in a row
  while (newFrequency === previousFrequency) {
    newFrequency = frequencies[Math.floor(Math.random() * frequencies.length)];
  }
  return newFrequency;
}

const frequencyFormatter = frequency => {
  if (frequency > 999) {
    return frequency / 1000 + ' k';
  }
  return frequency + ' ';
}

(function() {
  'use strict';
  let difficultyMode = 'easy'; // default difficulty mode
  let frequencyTrainer = startFrequencyTrainer(difficultyMode);
  let frequency = frequencyTrainer.frequency;
  let frequencyContainers = null;
  const frequencyGrid = document.getElementsByClassName('grid')[0];
  const controls = document.getElementsByClassName('controls')[0];

  // Control buttons
  const startButton = document.getElementById('start-button');
  startButton.onclick = function() {
    stopToneGenerator();
    startToneGenerator(frequency, volumeControl, 0, 3);
  };
  const stopButton = document.getElementById('stop-button');
  stopButton.onclick = function() {
    stopToneGenerator();
  };
  const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-button');
  nextButton.onclick = function() {
    stopToneGenerator();
    stopFrequencyTrainer();
    frequency = startFrequencyTrainer(difficultyMode, frequency).frequency;
    startToneGenerator(frequency, volumeControl, 0.05, 3);
  };
  let volumeControl = document.getElementById('volume-control');
  volumeControl.oninput = changeVolume.bind(null, volumeControl);

  const fillFrequencyGrid = frequencies => {
    frequencyGrid.innerHTML = '';
    frequencies.forEach(function(frequency) {
      const frequencyFormatted = frequencyFormatter(frequency);
      frequencyGrid.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="frequency-container" data-frequency="' + frequency + '">' + frequencyFormatted + 'Hz</div>');
    });
  };
  frequencyGrid.addEventListener('click', event => {
    const target = event.target;
    if (target.classList.contains('frequency-container')) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      let frequencyChosen = target.getAttribute('data-frequency');
      let frequencyChosenFormatted = frequencyFormatter(frequencyChosen);

      stopToneGenerator();
      if (frequencyChosen === frequency) {
        if (window.confirm(frequencyChosenFormatted + 'Hz is correct!\nLet\'s try another one!')) {
          stopFrequencyTrainer();
          frequency = startFrequencyTrainer(difficultyMode, frequency).frequency;
          startToneGenerator(frequency, volumeControl, 0.05, 3);
        }
      } else {
        window.alert(frequencyChosenFormatted + 'Hz is not correct.\nPlease try again.');
        startToneGenerator(frequency, volumeControl, 0.05, 3);
      }
    }
  }, true);


  // Generate frequency grid
  fillFrequencyGrid(frequencyTrainer.frequencies);
  controls.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('difficulty-button')) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      stopToneGenerator();
      stopFrequencyTrainer();
      difficultyMode = event.target.getAttribute('data-difficulty');
      frequencyTrainer = startFrequencyTrainer(difficultyMode, frequency);
      frequency = frequencyTrainer.frequency;
      fillFrequencyGrid(frequencyTrainer.frequencies);
    }
  }, false);
}());
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
}

a {
  color: #0000BB;
}

a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 1vw);
}

.body {
  max-width: 1500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.title {
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
}

.content {
  padding: 30px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
}

.controls {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
}

.volume-control {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 80%;
}

.footer {
  padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
}

.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(84px, 1fr));
}

.frequency-container {
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(30px + 0.2vw);
  text-shadow: 0 0 25px white;
}

.frequency-container:before {
  content: '';
  padding-top: 100%;
  float: left;
}

[data-frequency="20"] {
  background: #CC2828;
}

[data-frequency="25"] {
  background: #CC3028;
}

[data-frequency="31.5"] {
  background: #CC3928;
}

[data-frequency="40"] {
  background: #CC4128;
}

[data-frequency="50"] {
  background: #CC4928;
}

[data-frequency="63"] {
  background: #CC5128;
}

[data-frequency="80"] {
  background: #CC5928;
}

[data-frequency="100"] {
  background: #CC6128;
}

[data-frequency="125"] {
  background: #CC6A28;
}

[data-frequency="160"] {
  background: #CC7228;
}

[data-frequency="200"] {
  background: #CC7A28;
}

[data-frequency="250"] {
  background: #CC8228;
}

[data-frequency="315"] {
  background: #CC8A28;
}

[data-frequency="400"] {
  background: #CC9228;
}

[data-frequency="500"] {
  background: #CC9B28;
}

[data-frequency="630"] {
  background: #CCAB28;
}

[data-frequency="800"] {
  background: #CCBB28;
}

[data-frequency="1000"] {
  background: #CCCC28;
}

[data-frequency="1250"] {
  background: #BBCC28;
}

[data-frequency="1600"] {
  background: #ABCC28;
}

[data-frequency="2000"] {
  background: #9BCC28;
}

[data-frequency="2500"] {
  background: #8ACC28;
}

[data-frequency="3150"] {
  background: #7ACC28;
}

[data-frequency="4000"] {
  background: #6ACC28;
}

[data-frequency="5000"] {
  background: #59CC28;
}

[data-frequency="6300"] {
  background: #49CC28;
}

[data-frequency="8000"] {
  background: #39CC28;
}

[data-frequency="10000"] {
  background: #28CC28;
}

[data-frequency="12500"] {
  background: #28CC39;
}

[data-frequency="16000"] {
  background: #28CC49;
}

[data-frequency="20000"] {
  background: #28CC59;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:900" />
<div class="body">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Frequency Trainer</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="start-button" class="control-button">Start</button>
    <button type="button" id="stop-button" class="control-button">Stop</button>
    <button type="button" id="next-button" class="control-button">Next</button><br />
    <br /> Volume:
    <br />
    <input type="range" id="volume-control" class="volume-control" min="0" max="20" value="2" step="0.1" /><br />
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="difficulty-easy" class="difficulty-button" data-difficulty="easy">Easy</button>
    <button type="button" id="difficulty-normal" class="difficulty-button" data-difficulty="normal">Normal</button>
    <button type="button" id="difficulty-hard" class="difficulty-button" data-difficulty="hard">Hard</button>
    <button type="button" id="difficulty-pro" class="difficulty-button" data-difficulty="pro">Pro</button><br />
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <a href="https://github.com/MaxVMH/frequency-trainer/tree/v.0.0.4-alpha">v.0.0.4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive feedback, I’ll have more time after the weekend to look at your review more closely so I might have some questions then but for now everything looks pretty straight-forward :)

Comment: Alrighty- I expanded the section on `let` and `const` variables